# `passenger-enterprise-server` gem support arm64 architecture

Tags: passenger

We are installing Passenger Enterprise gem in ruby v3.1.3. I want to know does passanger enterprise v6.0.12 support arm64(al2) architecture.

We are getting error while installing the gem.

Installing Command:

```
gem install --version $PASSENGER_VERSION --source https://download:$key@www.phusionpassenger.com/enterprise_gems/ passenger-enterprise-server
```

Error:

> <jemalloc>: Error in munmap(): Invalid argument

We have build our ruby from source with jemallac.

```
./configure prefix=/opt/ruby-3.1.3 --enable-shared --with-jemalloc --disable-install-doc
make
make test
make install
```